# ¿Como agrego una accion por cada elemento de un context menu strip en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menú

tengo un Context Menu Stripe que se activa cuando doy clic derecho sobre una celda de mi datagridview , agregue mis elementos por codigo pero ahora no se como hacer que al dar clic en cada opcion haga una accion diferete , les muestro mi codigo hasta el momento

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

            menu.Items.Add("Nueva Venta").Name = "VENTA";
            menu.Items.Add("Historial").Name = "HISTORIAL";
            menu.Items.Add("Modificar").Name = "MODIFICAR";


            //Obtienes las coordenadas de la celda seleccionada. 
            Rectangle coordenada = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);

            int anchoCelda = coordenada.Location.X; //Ancho de la localizacion de la celda
            int altoCelda = coordenada.Location.Y;  //Alto de la localizacion de la celda

            //Para mostrar el MENU 
            int X = anchoCelda + dataGridView1.Location.X;
            int Y = altoCelda + dataGridView1.Location.Y - 90;

            menu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(X, Y));
        }
    }
```

Por ejemplo quiero que al dar clic en el boton del menu "venta" me habra mi form donde realizo mis ventas, muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar la sobrecarga `Add(string text, Image image, EventHandler onClick)`, de esta manera, con el tercer parámetro definirías la acción del Click en el item

Por ejemplo:

```
menu.Items.Add("Nueva Venta",default(Image),(snd,evt) => { MessageBox.Show("Hice click en Nueva Venta!"); })
```

También podrías definir el `EventHandler` en otro método para una mejor legibilidad de la siguiente manera:

```
menu.Items.Add("Nueva Venta",default(Image), ClickNuevaVenta);

private void ClickNuevaVenta(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Click en NUeva Venta!");
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ocupe tu segunda opción, solo cambie los nombres de los parametros por que me mandaba error , busque mucho por internet y me extraña que en verdad no haya casi información al respecto